# What WWI biplane is this model?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What WWI biplane is this model?

[image]
[image]
[image]

(own work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first guess (but it is a guess) is an AirCo/de Haviland DH.4.

Reference: https://www.militaryfactory.com/aircraft/detail.asp?aircraft_id=448

Answer (score 0):

[image]
<sup>[source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Martinsyde_g100.jpg)</sup>

It looks to me like the British [Martinsyde Elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martinsyde_G.100). 271 were built.

Answer (score -1):

Avro 504. You can see a photograph of the original [here](http://www.adf-gallery.com.au/gallery/albums/Avro-504/7_Squadron_AFC_Leighterton_c_1918_Avro_504Ks_F9754_and_E1895.jpg).

Comment: Several avro photos seem to suggest the engine casing is almost circular and the tail having a funnier shape when compared to the photos above.

Comment: @Thunderstrike: That appears to be correct. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9k7yxab6H8